# Flask - render page without return

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on an application, where user fills in form. 
One of the fields asks for postcode. When request is sent, a separate thread runs python code using PYQT5, rendering page and scraping web, (don't want to pay for API from google) providing mileage between given postcode and set postcode. Results of this thread are saved in a file.

What i would like to do is to open a new webpage with information that the data is being checked. This page would run python code, which checks for results in a file (that takes up to few seconds) using while loop. if the result is in the file, the page redirect to another page.

Is there a way to render a page (or redirect to another page) without using RETURN? i understand that when I use `return render_templates (page)`, rest of the code is ignored.

```
@app.route('/add_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_user():
    file = open('app/results_from_g.txt','w')
    file.write('')
    file.close()
    form = AddForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = 'https://google.co.uk/maps/dir/...'
        def sendtogoogle(url):    
            os.system('python googlemaps_mileage.py ' +url)                
        thread1=threading.Thread(target=sendtogoogle, args=(url,))
        thread1.start()
```

the next line of the code should be redirect to another page, and when results are in the file, either back here, or different page:

```
while result_from_file==0:
            file = open('results_from_g.txt','r')
            result_from_file = file.read()
            if result_from_file =='': #means no data saved in the file yet    
                time.sleep(1)
            elif wynik =='0': #means wrong postcode
                //render page 'wrong postcode'
            else:              
                //render page 'correct postcode
```

Comment: I see that my question is not clear. Simply, is there a way of redirecting to a page without using 'return' statement? hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: I believe this question might actually be a little broad, as there are several problems with your approach to the original problem (starting a thread is probably not a good idea, for one, nor does it make sense to call `os.system()` from a thread to do your work).  Instead, if the scraping is slow and labor intensive what you might want is a background service that handles that outside of your web server, and use a message-passing framework to send and receive scraping jobs and pass the results back to the client.

Comment: On the client side, then, you have many approaches but you will want to use some JavaScript to wait for a result and then display it.  You could use websockets to push results directly to the client when they are ready; use older polling techniques to poll at a specific URL, etc. (when the client submits the form you might intercept the submit with JavaScript and instead send the request to a handler that returns, among other things, a generated URL where that client's result will be available).  There are many ways to do this.

Comment: Iguananaut - Thanks for the answer. in relation to the first problem I used os.system() as this is the only one i know. looks like there is still a lot to learn. I don't want to sound silly, but why os.system() is a bad idea? it does the job. web scraping is not that slow, but as i'm scrapping from maps.google.com, it requires the page to load first, therefore i used different thread.

Comment: In relation to the second problem i have spent some time reading about the problems and looks like javascript will be the one. - easiest one. Thank you for your help